# How can i set limit to text area in " Email to a friend "

Tags: template, frontend, forms, html

I want to set a maximum length of words to the "message" text field in the "email to a friend" template.

Answer (score 1):

The email a friend template can be found at `/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sendfriend/send.phtml` in here there is a textarea that deals with the message. Here you could simply add the attribute `maxlength="50"` and this would limit the length on the front end. When doing this I would create a layout xml update that changes the template to your new file. There are two layout handle for email to a friend `sendfriend_product_send` and `catalog_product_send` so something like.

```
<sendfriend_product_send>
    <reference name="sendfriend.send">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/your/template.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</sendfriend_product_send>
<catalog_product_send>
    <reference name="sendfriend.send">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>path/to/your/template.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_send>
```

Answer (score 1):

As David said, the template is this: `template/sendfriend/send.phtml`

But you don't need a template update, instead you could just create your own template in your theme.

But as David didn't say but meant: DON'T TOUCH CORE FILES. :-)

Comment: Indeed, don't touch the core files :)